# Undefined function make_card Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am doing a practice problem black jack card game in ruby, references I am using are

https://medium.com/quick-code/using-ruby-classes-to-implement-a-game-of-blackjack-535a786c417

I am getting error that says undefined method "make_card"

**Code for my Deck Class**

```
class Deck
  def initialize
    @faces = [*(2..10),'Jack','Queen','King','Ace']
    @suits = ['clubs','spades','hearts','diamonds']
    @cards = []

    @faces.each do |face|

      if face.class == "Integer"
        value = face
      elsif face == 'Ace'
        value = 11
      else
        value = 10
      end
      @suits.each do |suit|
         @cards <<  Card.new(face,suit,value)
      end
    end
    @cards.shuffle!
  end

  def make_card(participant)

    fresh_card = Card.new(face,suit,value)
    participant.turn << fresh_card
    participant.total = participant.total + fresh_card.value
  end

  def deal(number,participant)
    number.times{@cards.shift.make_card(participant)}
  end
end
```

As both methods are in same class I am still getting that error

Comment: Yes I posted solution already. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by placing method in Card class and accessing it via its instance variable

```
class Card
  attr_accessor :face, :suit, :value

  def initialize(face,suit,value)
    @face = face
    @suit = suit
    @value = value
  end
  def make_card(participant)

    fresh_card = Card.new(face,suit,value)
    participant.turn << fresh_card
    participant.total = participant.total + fresh_card.value
  end
end

class Deck
  def initialize
    @faces = [*(2..10),'Jack','Queen','King','Ace']
    @suits = ['clubs','spades','hearts','diamonds']
    @cards = []

    @faces.each do |face|

      if face.class == Integer
        value = face
      elsif face == 'Ace'
        value = 11
      else
        value = 10
      end
      @suits.each do |suit|
         @cards <<  Card.new(face,suit,value)
      end
    end
    @cards.shuffle!
  end



  def deal(number,participant)
    number.times{@cards.shift.make_card(participant)}
  end
end
```